# New Comer to JS Looking for Guidance

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. Can anyone share some good advice on getting started? I have a little experience in ActionScript 3 and have taken a few Java classes toward my CS degree but my background is of a designer transitioning into development. My goal is to become a well rounded front-end developer and I'd like to move beyond the simple slideshow animations and rollover effects. Any guidance/wisdom will be much appreciated!

Comment: "and have taken a few Java classes" ... javascript is not java .. or even related.

Comment: There are many questions here on SO that pertain to getting started with javascript. Here's one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970961/getting-started-with-javascript You can search SO using the search box on the top right. You'll find dozens of questions pointing to all sorts of resources.

Comment: this should be on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159226/is-there-a-more-comprehensive-javascript-function-reference-than-w3schools) question for good suggestions about JS APIs.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I know Java is not related to JavaScript. I've taken a few Java classes so I know the difference in the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to become a good javascript coder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978637/how-to-become-a-good-javascript-coder)

Answer (score 4):

I'll recommend some reading materials:

**Beginner**: [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996)

**Intermediate**: [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752)

**Advanced**: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

The best way to learn is practice. Write a simple application. When you are done, rewrite it so you learn what you did wrong last time. Perhaps, rewrite it again. Then, take on a new project. Repeat :).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm reading Javascript: The Definitive Guide now. Great book. Out of curiosity, what kinds of simple applications have you started out with? I'm creating a slideshow from scratch in JS and it's not easy for me but I'm learning alot.

Comment: The first project in which I used custom JavaScript was a simple Content Management System (CMS). It did basic things: add and delete rows, basic input validation, shading even rows in the table. This was before I had learned jQuery (a JavaScript framework that I highly recommend, once you have a good handle on JavaScript itself)

Answer (score 2):

Watch the Crockford lectures:

Part 1: http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111593
Part 2: http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111594
Part 3: http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111595
Part 4: http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111596

Search for other JavaScript lectures at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to recognize the ECMA follows prototypal inheritance, not classical inheritance.  Also, JS is a dynamic language, so be sure to understand how you can modify objects at runtime.  Knowledge of good design patterns (MVC) are essential to writing concise and effective clients.  Finally, in order to be a good client side developer, it doesn't hurt to understand server side development principles and how the back-ends to the applications work.  By that I mean you don't need to understand the details of how requests are handled at a technical level, but rather you need to understand the implications of how tools like AJAX can put strain on your server resources.  Or why your colleagues working on the server will be concerned with things like 'transactions' -- it doesn't hurt to have knowledge of server side implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm beginning to see just how expressive JavaScript is.